Cannot find putIceberg on nifi
I have been working with Apache NiFi and have attempted to install multiple versions, specifically 1.19.0, 1.23.2, and 1.27.0. However, I have encountered an issue where I cannot find the PutIceberg processor in any of these versions.
Hope to receive help from everyone!

I think this thread has the answers you are looking for; https://lists.apache.org/thread/ckso6nhswlzy7r0zzslw9o8ts78x3yzt
disclaimer: I'm a dev advocate from Datavolo, but we have a PutIcebergTable processor in our runtime and I created a tutorial for it at https://devcenter.datavolo.io/tutorials/populate-iceberg-polaris/ (I know that is NOT what you asked about, but thought I'd share it in case there's some interest at all -- no worries if not).
Good luck!
